# Error 503 in HTTP during page parsing in java

Tags: java, url, ioexception

Today I'm developing a java RMI server (and also the client) that gets info from a page and returns me what I want. I put the code right down here. The problem is that sometimes the url I pass to the method throws an IOException that says that the url given makes a 503 HTTP error. It could be easy if it was always that way but the thing is that it appears sometimes. 
I have this method structure because the page I parse is from a weather company and I want info from many cities, not only for one, so some cities works perfectly at the first chance and others it fails. Any suggestions?

```
public ArrayList<Medidas> parse(String url){
        medidas = new ArrayList<Medidas>();
        int v=0;

            String sourceLine;
            String content = "";
        try{
            // The URL address of the page to open.

            URL address = new URL(url);

            // Open the address and create a BufferedReader with the source code.
            InputStreamReader pageInput = new InputStreamReader(address.openStream());
            BufferedReader source = new BufferedReader(pageInput);

            // Append each new HTML line into one string. Add a tab character.
            while ((sourceLine = source.readLine()) != null){
                if(sourceLine.contains("<tbody>")) v=1;
                else if (sourceLine.contains("</tbody>"))
                    break;
                 else if(v==1)
                    content += sourceLine + "\n";
            }
       ........................
       ........................  NOW THE PARSING CODE, NOT IMPORTANT
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 500 errors reflect server errors so it has likely nothing to do with your client code.
You would get a 400 error if you were passing invalid parameters on your request.

503 is "Service Unavailable" and may be sent by the server when it is overloaded and cannot process your request. From a publicly accessible server, that could explain the erratic behavior.

**Edit**

Build a retry handler in your code when you detect a 503. Apache [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/) can do that automatically for you.

[List of HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Done, it was not my fault. Today everything works fine, I think the page server was been repaired. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the IOException is really not a MalformedURLException.  Try printing out the URLs to verify a bad URL is not causing the IOException.
2. How large is the file you are parsing?  Perhaps your JVM is running out of memory.

Comment: I think is not that because it sometimes works and others it does not. The page is about 55000 characters so I think it is not the problem

Comment: How are you passing the `String url` to the method?  Please provide sample urls.

Comment: Which line is throwing the IOException?

Comment: The url is a static url and it only changes 4 or 5 characters between cities.

Comment: An example of exception is  "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/observacion/ultimosdatos?k=gal&l=1442U&w=0&datos=det&x=h24&f=temperatura" where the 1442U string is what changes if there is one or other city

Comment: The line that throws the exception is   InputStreamReader pageInput = new InputStreamReader(address.openStream());